# Ignoring intermediate pipeline output

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I've created a few cmdlets. They all use common parameters so I'm splatting and `PSBoundParameters` and using pipelining. In the example below `Set-Body` and `Set-Labels` both return the same `PSBoundParameters` that was passed into them and finally my `New-Page` cmdlet returns `$returnObj` which contains overlapping parameters with `PSBoundParameters` that were passed in

```bash
function New-Page {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [object]$Arg_A,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$Arg_B        
    )
    process {
        $addPage = Add-Page @PSBoundParameters
        $addPage | Set-Body | Set-Labels 
        # SOME MORE LOGIC HAPPENING HERE TO CREATE $returnObj
        return $returnobj
    }
}
```

When I debug this code and step through it `$returnObj` contains a single object with `Arg_A, Arg_B`. However the calling code received an array with two instances for ex

```bash
$result = New-Page -Arg_A "AAA" -Arg_B "BBB"

#$result value is:
[0]: @{Arg_A="AAA"; Arg_B="BBB"}
[1]: @{Arg_A="AAA"; Arg_B="BBB"}
```

I would have expected a single instance but I've figured out the array is because `Set-Labels` is implicitly returning `Arg_A, Arg_B` to the pipeline and the function itself is also returning `$result` to the pipeline.

I know I can use `Out-Null` at the end of the pipeline like this `$addPage | Set-Body | Set-Labels | Out-Null` and this fixes the issue. This feels very risky to have results silently added to the pipeline and that one needs to resort to defensive coding.

My question is this; Is this the only way, is there a better way or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: have your function return only `$returnobj` and pipe `| Set-Body | Set-Labels` yourself. It seems like you're wanting your function to produce 2 different outputs at a time which doesnt categorize as a good practice

Comment: I'm trying to encapsulate logic. I only want one output `$returnobj` I dont really care about the output coming from `| Set-Labels` however if that function was used in isolation somewhere else the output may be important

Comment: If you don't care about that output then use `Out-Null` or `$null =` as you've already noted

Comment: I know I can do this, I was just asking if there is a better way to handle unexpected output by cmdlets to avoid polluting the pipeline with additional data when I'm not expecting it